# Why doesn't TypeScript narrow array types?

Tags: typescript, narrowing

Why is it that TypeScript doesn't narrow the type of arrays?

```js
function test(input: (string | number)[]): string[] {
  // The type of .map(...) reports that it returns string[].
  input = input.map(x => x.toString())
  // Type error: Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  return input
}
```

The workaround is not depending on it narrowing the type by just immediately using or assigning to a fresh variable:

```js
function test(input: (string | number)[]): string[] {
  return input.map(x => x.toString())
}

function test(input: (string | number)[]): string[] {
  const newInput = input.map(x => x.toString())
  return newInput
}
```

I did try casting, but in hindsight that obviously only works on use, e.g. `return input as string[]`, and will not narrow the type, as `.map(...)` already returns the correctly narrowed type.

It feels counter intuitive to me having to do these workarounds. **Why is it that TypeScript cannot narrow this array type and are there better workarounds available?**

I did look into the official documentation and looked at similar questions on Stack Overflow, but unless I have overlooked something, I haven't seen this particular question answered with anything else than just to reassign.

It is what I am doing in my own code for now, but I just wish I knew why it is as it is and if I can do better.

```
> tsc --version                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Version 4.2.3
```

Comment: I think the answer to this is simply "because the compiler doesn't have a narrowing rule which does what you want". It could have a rule for array types like this, but it doesn't, perhaps because the situation is not common enough that anyone has requested it yet. I didn't find a feature request on the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) about this.

Comment: @kaya3 probably [ms/TS#16976](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16976) is the relevant feature request (although it's not like it specifically mentions arrays).  Hey look I even linked [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8513#issuecomment-217871478) which explains some possible issues with implementing it.  So they've definitely *considered* it, but it doesn't look like it's high on anyone's priority list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For better or worse, [narrowing based on assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) or generally narrowing via [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) (as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#8010](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8010) *only happens when the variables involved have [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)*.  And by union type I mean where the type is itself directly a union, like `{a: string} | {a: number}` or `Array<string> | Array<number>`.  A single object type with union-typed properties like `{a: string | number}` is not itself a union; nor is a generic `interface` specified with a union-typed type parameter like `Array<string | number>`. There is a longstanding suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#16976](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16976) to support non-union control flow narrowing, but there's no indication when or if this will ever be implemented.   So `input = input.map(x => x.toString())` won't modify the apparent type of `input`.

There are other narrowing type guards in TypeScript, such as the `in` operator, or the `instanceof` operator, and you can write your own [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) or an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) which can narrow the types of their inputs.  None of these help you much here; by far the best workaround is just not to reuse the same variable to represent two different non-union types, as you know.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately not the answer I was hoping for, but the issue you linked is pretty clear on the matter. I also checked the 4.4-beta and it too still fails. The workarounds will have to do.

Comment: @MatthijsSteen yeah, ms/TS#16976 is probably the closest we have to a definitive answer to this question.  "Q: Why doesn't this narrow? A: We haven't implemented that" followed by nothing for four years.  If you really care a lot about this you might make a note in that issue, (preferably with a compelling use case and why the workaround isn't sufficient), but I wouldn't be optimistic about seeing a change.

Comment: It probably is just obvious and safe in specific cases like mine, but a problematic thing in the general case, which the compiler builders have to consider. Though it is not like they never add support for specific cases, though I am indeed not optimistic.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the concept of type narrowing does not really apply well here unless we actually go with more code.

```
function isStringArray(x: any[]): x is string[] {
  return x.every(i => typeof i === "string");
}

function test(input: (string | number)[]): string[] {
  // The type of .map(...) reports that it returns string[].
  input = input.map(x => x.toString())
  if (isStringArray(input)) {
    return input;   
  }
  return [];
}
```

This works because we use a [typeof type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards) inside a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) that is used inside of an `if`.

So if every element of the array is a string, return "true" which means the input array is an `string[]`. When used in an `if`, the "true" path narrows the type of `input` to `string[]` and we can return is successfully.

So while you think returning directly or assigning first to a new variable is a "work-around", you can see here that using TypeScript narrowing here is actually more code if you insist on re-using `input` than the alternatives that use the inherent type of the returned `.map`.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgZSgJxmA5gQU0wEMBPACgA8AuRYsUgbQF0BKWy5FRFLHXFogDeAKESJMAUyghMSSgDpJAN0mYKMRAF4AfIiikADpLjBk2rVsQAiXtjzXWAbhEBfESNCRYCfZN7kOIYgULTkdvyIAD6IYCAAtgBGaqws7Dx8eIKi4gD0uYgAKgAWkvpGZaaICvHEhuQKjawSkoZwmFDcUMXEUMh9UjJy3BFZzApiyGDBfVZBITV1VNp6ilBwGPa45KyskzBmgeiZBERkgdMhu8KT4oOySPNQTuKIk+530g+ILC6uQA)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Hadn't considered this particular workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Because `input` is already explicitly typed as `(string | number)[]` and you cannot change its type.

So when you do `input = input.map(x => x.toString())` you're assigning a `string[]` to a variable already typed as `(string | number)[]` (which is compatible) and not changing the type of `input` itself.

This is actually very helpful, because types are not "mutable." You shouldn't mutate your variables either, and being unable to change the type of an existing variable helps you from making mistakes like that.

Comment: "and you cannot change its type" - but you can narrow in some circumstances, for example if the type is `string[] | number[]` instead of `(string | number)[]` then the OP's code works correctly because of narrowing. So this doesn't answer the question, which is why you can't narrow in *this* circumstance.

Comment: *"being unable to change the type of an existing variable helps you from making mistakes like that."* - but Typescript *emphatically does* change the type of an existing variable by narrowing in some circumstances. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html

Comment: That's because `string[] | number[]` is a union type, but `(string | number)[]` is not.

Comment: I guess I've never considered narrowing or using typeguards to be "changing" a type, only being "more specific when previously it was ambiguous" - the type of the variable itself doesn't change, we just know more about it.

Comment: Like the other commenters mention, what you answered is not the case: `function test(input: string | number): string { input = input.toString(); return input }` works just fine.

Comment: @MatthijsSteen again, `string | number` is a union type, but `(string | number)[]` is _not_ a union type.

Comment: @xdumaine Narrowing is not only done for union types; for example the `instanceof` operator can narrow the type of a class instance into a subclass. So "it's not a union" isn't really an answer either.

Comment: Narrowing *via assignment* is only done for union types.  I'm afraid I don't understand the distinction between the type of narrowing you are calling "mutating" vs "non-mutating but just knowing more about it".  If you find out that a value of type `{a: string | number}` is `{a: 3}` it isn't "mutating" the type to treat it like `{a: number}` or even `{a: 3}`' it's just "knowing more" about it.   The fact that this happens for unions and not for objects still seems to need explanation.